# UNION or JOIN for SELECT from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

### My Issue

I am trying to select one row from multiple tables based on parameters, but my limited knowledge of SQL joining is holding me back. Could somebody possibly point me in the right direction?

Consider these table structures:

```
+-----------------------+     +---------------------+
| Customers             |     | Sellers             |
+-------------+---------+     +-----------+---------+
| Customer_ID | Warning |     | Seller_ID | Warning |
+-------------+---------+     +-----------+---------+
| 00001       | Test 1  |     | 00008     | Testing |
| 00002       | Test 2  |     | 00010     | Testing |
+-------------+---------+     +-----------+---------+
```

What I would like to do is one `SELECT` to retrieve only one row, and in this row will be the 'Warning' field for each of the tables based on the X_ID field.

### Desired Results

So, if I submitted the following information, I would receive the following results:

Example 1:

```
Customer_ID = 00001
Seller_ID = 00008

Results:
+-----------------------------------+
| Customer_Warning | Seller_Warning |
+------------------+----------------+
| Test 1           | Testing        |
+------------------+----------------+
```

Example 2:

```
Customer_ID = 00001
Seller_ID = 00200

Results:
+-----------------------------------+
| Customer_Warning | Seller_Warning |
+------------------+----------------+
| Test 1           | NULL           |
+------------------+----------------+
```

### What I Have Tried

This is my current code (I am receiving loads of rows):

```
SELECT c.Warning 'Customer_Warning', s.Warning AS 'Seller_Warning'
FROM Customers c,Sellers s
WHERE c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID
    OR s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID
```

But I have also played around with `UNION`, `UNION ALL` and `JOIN`. Which method should I go for?

Comment: Although this is possible in SQL, why would you want to hold non-related data in one row?

Comment: @WeSt I am reading it into PHP which is feeding a web application

Comment: Still, why not have two queries or one query with a flag? Just from a design point, there is no sense in putting them together in a row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're not really joining tables together, just selecting a single row from each, you could do this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Warning 
     FROM Customers 
     WHERE Customer_ID = @Customer_ID) AS Customer_Warning,
    (SELECT Warning 
     FROM Sellers 
     WHERE Seller_ID = @Seller_ID) AS Seller_Warning
```

Comment: Didn't think about using subqueries... Think this may be the solution

Comment: This is the correct solution for the proposed situation, a join is not applicable here since there is no existing relation between one entry and the other. Joins specifically should be used to merge two tables based on a common factor.

Comment: Haven't decided which method to use yet but thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Well obviously you pick the one with the most upvotes! Just kidding of course. Since you mention more tables (6!) then this may look slightly easier to understand than a full outer join.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're getting a cartesian product of rows in each table where *either* column has the value you're looking for.

I think you just want `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT c.Warning 'Customer_Warning', s.Warning AS 'Seller_Warning'
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Sellers s
ON c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID
    AND s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID
```

If performance isn't good enough you could join two filtered subqueries:

```
SELECT c.Warning 'Customer_Warning', s.Warning AS 'Seller_Warning'
FROM (SELECT Warnning FROM Customers WHERE c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID) c,
     (SELECT Warning FROM Sellers s WHERE s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID) s
```

But I suspect SQL will be able to optimize the filtered join just fine.

> it wont return a row if one of the ID's doesnt exist.

Then you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.Warning 'Customer_Warning', s.Warning AS 'Seller_Warning'
FROM Customers c 
FULL OUTER JOIN Sellers s
ON c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID
    AND s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID
```

Comment: Correct, and that requirement wasn't stated in your question. I have updated my answer for that requirement.

Comment: I do apologise, I thought my second results example made that clear. I gave you +1 anyway to thank you for your input :-)

Comment: OK I see that now - the FULL OUTER JOIN should work in that case.

Comment: Do you reckon a `OUTER JOIN` is better than a few subqueries?

Comment: Performance wise?  I don't know - you'd have to run them both and compare.  It think it _looks_ cleaner, but that's completely subjective.

Comment: I agree it does look cleaner :-). Can't decide. Regardless, thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you are facing is that when one of the tables has no rows, you are going to get no rows out.

I would suggest solving this with a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT c.Warning as Customer_Warning, s.Warning AS Seller_Warning
FROM Customers c FULL OUTER JOIN
     Sellers s
     ON c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID AND s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID;
```

Also, I strongly discourage you from using single quotes for column aliases.  Use single quotes *only* for string and date constants.  Using them for column names can lead to confusion.  In this case, you don't need delimiters on the names at all.

Comment: I'm curious, how efficient is this compared to my answer that doesn't use a join? Would it use indexes in the best way?

Comment: Don't know why I used the single quotes, guess I wasn't thinking when I wrote the example query. For the purposes of this example, I have left out multiple tables, is it possible to use this method on multiple tables, not just two?

Comment: @BenCarey . . . Yes, this will work on multiple tables.  One caution:  if you have multiple rows that match in some tables, you may get more rows than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen so far here are working examples for your scenario. However, there is no real sense behind putting unrelated data together in one row. I would propose using a `UNION` and separate the values in your code:

```
SELECT 'C' AS Type, c.Warning
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.Customer_ID = @Customer_ID
UNION
SELECT 'S' AS Type, s.Warning
FROM Sellers s
WHERE s.Seller_ID = @Seller_ID
```

You can use the flag to distinguish the warnings in your code. This will be more efficient then joining or sub queries and will be easy to understand later on (when refactoring). I know this is not 100% what you ask for in your question but that's why I challenge the question :)

Comment: I have already tried this, and also, I did not mention in my question as I didn't want to over complicate it, but I am actually selecting from more than two tables (6 to be precise)!

Comment: Then there is even more reason to use a `UNION`, since sub queries are very expensive and `FULL OUTER JOIN`s can be as well. No matter which solution you take, I wouldn't recommend a join, since they are by design made for merging related data. Sub queries or `UNION` is the way to go imho.